# How do you pronounce two variable values listed one on top of the other?

Tags: terminology, mathematics, reading-aloud

Long story short I need to figure out how to verbalize this equation:

[image: equation]

Comment: "The integral from zero to one...evaluated at y equals one and y equals zero..."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it concerns domain-specific terminology that would be unknown to the average native Anglophone. IMHO it belongs on [SO Maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You really really don't need to verbalise that equation.  Mathematical notation is not intended to be read aloud.  It is a written notation,  leave it as that..  (fwiw, I use square brackets for the limits of the integrated expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read it as follows. Note that the dashes (`-`) are hyphens showing connection between spoken terms, not minus signs; I have spelled out "minus" where I would say it. Letters on their own are pronounced as single letters (i.e. "eee," "exks," "wye," "dee").

- The integral from zero to one of (e to the negative-x-y minus x-y e to the negative-x-y) d-y
  ...equals...
- (y e to the negative-x-y evaluated at y equals 1) minus (y e to the negative-x-y) evaluated at y equals 0)
  ...equals...
- e to the negative-x

I might actually say "minus-x-y" in the exponent instead of the proper "negative-x-y" because it's one fewer syllable. You could also insert "times" at the appropriate locations if you wanted to.

You can see that the "two variables on top of each other" operator is pronounced "*X* evaluated at y=1 minus *X* evaluated at y=0" and that is exactly what you do to find the result.

Comment: It's a nuance, but I'd say this answer first mathematically evaluates the bar term ye^{-xy}|^{y=1}_{y=0} as ye^{-xy}|_{y=1} - ye^{-xy}|_{y = 0} and *then* reads the (equivalent) result, similar to reading 2(x-1) as "2x minus 2" instead of "2 times the quantity x minus 1."

Comment: @Chemo, I'm not understanding how what you said is different from what I said.

Comment: There's no minus sign outside the integrand in the original expression. A second example: we read \sum_{i=0}^{i=2} i as "the sum of i from i=0 to i=2, not "0 plus 1 plus 2" and not "3."